# For loops and matrices, replacing rows

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to create a function `first_rpt` which will take as input matrix/array `M` and output an array which changes each row in the matrix to the values in row number 0 (first row).

If I have matrix `a=np.array([[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3]])` I would want the function to change that to `a=[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]`

```
def first_rpt(M):  
    new_array=M    
    M=np.array(M)    
    for i in len(M):    
    M[i]=M[0]    
    return new_array
```

This code brings back error `"int" object is not iterable`. Changing `len(M)` to `range(len(M))` just outputs the same matrix inputted.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just try `a[1:]=a[0]
`

Comment: Shouldn't you be returning `M` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[U9-Forward's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54273049/4518341) is ideal, but since you insist on iterating over the array...

Just remove `new_array` and iterate over a range.

```
def first_rpt(M):
    for i in xrange(len(M)):  # "xrange" in case the array is very big
        M[i] = M[0]
    return M
```

In your code you assigned `new_array = M`, but then you reassigned `M`, which meant `new_array` was left pointing to the old `M`. You could also fix the problem by moving `new_array = M` after reassigning `M`, but there's no point.

---

Full test code

```
import numpy as np

def first_rpt(M):
    for i in xrange(len(M)):
        M[i] = M[0]
    return M

a = np.array([[1,1,1], [2,2,2], [3,3,3]])
print first_rpt(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a=np.array([[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3]])
>>> def first_rpt(M):
    M[1:]=M[0]
    return M

>>> first_rpt(a)
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1]])
>>>
```

Comment: So that works, but I am working on this for a python class and they want it specifically with the for loop involved... They usually ask for these things when they can be done easier.

Comment: @Ryan This is the easiest, the whole thing is just: `M[1:]=M[0]`, but you want loop... use the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
def first_rpt(M):  
   for i in range(1, len(M)):    
      M[i]=M[0]    
   return
```

In this task you don't need a "new_array"

Comment: You forgot to `return M`